# Migration of SQL server database to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm trying to migrate one of my database in my local environment to Azure from SQL server management studio, but i'm facing with the following exception.

Please let me know how to resolve this issue. Thanks

Steps I have followed:

1. From SQL Server Management Studio, Database -> Tasks --> Deploy database to Windows Azure SQL Database
2. I'm able to connect to the Azure SQL instance
3. During the process i'm getting the following error, as in the snapshot.

[image]

PFB the snapshot of my local and azure SQL server instances,
[image]

Comment: Are there any details on that error? Not positive, but perhaps the version difference may be the cause.

Comment: Also [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/09/19/deployment-fails-with-unable-to-connect-to-master-or-target-server-mydb_svr-you-must-have-a-user-with-the-same-password-in-master-or-target-server-mydb-db/)  recommends making sure you are on the latest release of SSDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click on the DB you are trying to copy, select "Generate scripts..." to open the "generate and Publish Scripts" wizard.
2. Click Next or "Choose Objects" from the navigation pane to the left. On the "Choose Objects" step you may want to select the specific tables/sprocs you want to copy, or you can just choose "Script entire database"
3. On the next page, I recommend selecting the "Save to a New Query Window" option. Then click "Advanced" in the top right corner and scroll to the bottom of the "General" section. The last item in this section is "Type of data to script". You will probably want to change this to "Schema and data" if you want to include the data in your script.
4. Click Next until it starts to generate the script. When the script is done, it will open a new query window with CREATE / INSERT statements and when you Execute, it will create a copy of your DB. HOWEVER, you will need to update the USE [MyDatabase] statement and you will need to change the "Available Databases" dropdown to the desired Database (i'm talking about the dropdown box above the Object Explorer)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I was able to generate the scripts as you mentioned. From SSMS, I have logged into Azure SQL instance, when i'm trying to run the scripts i'm getting the System out of memory exception, could you please help me why I would I be getting this error

Comment: Yes, when you get to the "Choose Objects" step, just select a fewer number of tables. Generate the script for the first 15 or so tables (depending on the size of each table) in your database and then generate an entirely new script for the next 15 and so on.

Comment: Also FYI if your tables are fairly large ( greater than 300k rows ) it will probably take a few hours to run. Just wanted to let you know so you're not thinking "this is taking too long, it's probably not working"

I recommend you limit the number of tables you copy each time because you don't want it to take 2 hours only to find there was a connection error and have to restart it

Comment: Thank you James. I will try this approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods:

- -dacpac
- -In Visual Studio -> Tools - SQL Server - SQL Schema comparison & data comparison

Check in the settings windows - use incompatible platforms

Answer (score 0):

You received that error because the version of SSMS you're using is old.  Installing the latest version of SSMS will get things working better.